# Only extern declared as const?

Tags: c, initialization, extern

Can I declare a variable which is populated at init time as a const only for external access?

Header:

```
// foo.h:
extern const int foo;
```

Source:

```
// foo.c:
int foo;


void init_foo()
{
    static bool initialized = false;
    if (!initialized)
        foo = rand();
    initialized = true;
}
```